# getting info from a database with js and php

Tags: php, javascript

I really hope someone can point me in the right direction as I am rather new to js.

I have a drop down nav menu the content being populated as below.

```
var anylinkmenu1={divclass:'anylinkmenu', inlinestyle:'', linktarget:''} 
anylinkmenu1.items=[
["Page 2 Subpage 1", "http://kellys-webdesigns.com/mpanetwork/index.php? id=8"],
["Page 2 Subpage 2", "http://kellys-webdesigns.com/mpanetwork/index.php? id=9"],
["Page 2 Subpage 3", "http://kellys-webdesigns.com/mpanetwork/index.php? id=10"],
["Page 2 Subpage 4", "http://kellys-webdesigns.com/mpanetwork/index.php? id=11"],
["Page 2 Subpage 5", "http://kellys-webdesigns.com/mpanetwork/index.php? id=12"],
["Page 2 Subpage 6", "http://kellys-webdesigns.com/mpanetwork/index.php? id=13"],
["Page 2 Subpage 7", "http://kellys-webdesigns.com/mpanetwork/index.php? id=14"],
["Page 2 Subpage 8", "http://kellys-webdesigns.com/mpanetwork/index.php? id=15"] 
]
var anylinkmenu2={divclass:'anylinkmenu', inlinestyle:'', linktarget:''} 
anylinkmenu2.items=[
["Page 3 Subpage 1", "http://kellys-webdesigns.com/mpanetwork/index.php? id=16"],
["Page 3 Subpage 2", "http://kellys-webdesigns.com/mpanetwork/index.php? id=17"],
["Page 3 Subpage 3", "http://kellys-webdesigns.com/mpanetwork/index.php? id=18"],
["Page 3 Subpage 4", "http://kellys-webdesigns.com/mpanetwork/index.php? id=19"],
["Page 3 Subpage 5", "http://kellys-webdesigns.com/mpanetwork/index.php? id=20"],
["Page 3 Subpage 6", "http://kellys-webdesigns.com/mpanetwork/index.php? id=21"],
["Page 3 Subpage 7", "http://kellys-webdesigns.com/mpanetwork/index.php? id=22"],
["Page 3 Subpage 8", "http://kellys-webdesigns.com/mpanetwork/index.php? id=23"] 
]
```

The contents are part of a database and rather than manually putting these values in I would like them to be taken from the database, is this possible? I think I need to use php to achieve this and I have no problem with the php code, I’m just not sure how to connect the js to the php.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make an `ajax` call, get the data and assign it to the `variables`.

Use `jquery` `library` or similar `library`.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can write javascript as well as HTML.

The following script assumes that $menuItems is an array of "title" and "url" from your database and that $totalItems is the number of items from $menuItems.

$totalItems is required because otherwise php would generate an additional "," (comma) at the end of the last item, which makes IE have a fit.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var anylinkmenu1={divclass:'anylinkmenu', inlinestyle:'', linktarget:''} 
    anylinkmenu1.items=[
    <?php $index=0;
        foreach ($menuItems as $item): ?>
        ["<?php echo $item["title"]; ?>", "<?php echo $item["url"] ?>"] <?php if ($index-1 > $totalItems) { echo ","; } ?>
    <?php $index += 1; endforeach; ?>
    ]
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but I am getting a syntax error in the above code and I can not find it for the life of me, any ideas? thanks

Comment: My apologies I missed a semi-colon at the end of the echo in the if statement. Fixed in my Answer.